# Close overlay on page refresh/revisit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML, CSS, and Javascript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getTarget(event){
    target = (typeof window.event === "undefined")?event.target:window.event.srcElement;
    return target;
}

document.onclick = function(event){
    var target = getTarget(event);
    if(target.id == ""){
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
        var button = document.getElementById('qualityButton');
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
        button.style.color="#000000";
    }

}


function toggleOverlay(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    var button = document.getElementById('qualityButton');
    overlay.style.opacity = .7;
    if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
        button.style.color="#000000";
    } else {
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        specialBox.style.display = "block";
        button.style.color="#ff0000";
    }
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">

div#overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #A9A9A9;
    position: fixed;
    width: 879px;
    height: 291px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
div#specialBox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 719px; 
    height: 215px;
    top: 88px;
    left: 80px;
    background: #FFF;
}
div#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .btn {
        cursor:pointer;
        font-size:24px;
        border:none;
        color:#000
}
    .btn:hover{ 
    color:#F00; 
    }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .x {
        background-color:white;
        cursor:pointer;
        font:Arial;
        font-size:14px;
        color:red;
        z-index: 4;
        position: fixed;
        top: 92px;
        left: 766px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<!-- Start Overlay -->
<div id="overlay"></div>
<!-- End Overlay -->
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<div id="specialBox">
  <button class="x" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">X</button>
</div>
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<!-- Start Normal Page Content -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <button id="qualityButton" class="btn" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">HIGHEST QUALITY</button>
</div>
<!-- End Normal Page Content -->



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The overlay opens and closes just fine. However, if the overlay is opened and the user visits another page on the website, and returns to the original page where the overlay was, the overlay still remains open...Is there a way to make the overlay close upon refreshing the page and upon returning to the page having visited another one?

Any help is much appreciated :)

James

Answer (score 2):

Try This using display none to the div which you want to hide while refreshing

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getTarget(event){
            target = (typeof window.event === "undefined")?event.target:window.event.srcElement;
            return target;
        }

        document.onclick = function(event){
            var target = getTarget(event);
            if(target.id == ""){
                var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
                var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
                var button = document.getElementById('qualityButton');
                overlay.style.display = "none";
                specialBox.style.display = "none";
                button.style.color="#000000";
            }

        }


        function toggleOverlay(){
            var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
            var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
            var button = document.getElementById('qualityButton');
            overlay.style.opacity = .7;
            if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
                overlay.style.display = "none";
                specialBox.style.display = "none";
                button.style.color="#000000";
            } else {
                overlay.style.display = "block";
                specialBox.style.display = "block";
                button.style.color="#ff0000";
            }
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

        div#overlay {
            display: none;
            z-index: 2;
            background: #A9A9A9;
            position: fixed;
            width: 879px;
            height: 291px;
            top: 50px;
            left: 0px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        div#specialBox {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 3;
            width: 719px;
            height: 215px;
            top: 88px;
            left: 80px;
            background: #FFF;
        }
        div#wrapper {
            position:absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            padding-left: 24px;
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        .btn {
            cursor:pointer;
            font-size:24px;
            border:none;
            color:#000
        }
        .btn:hover{
            color:#F00;
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        .x {
            background-color:white;
            cursor:pointer;
            font:Arial;
            font-size:14px;
            color:red;
            z-index: 4;
            position: fixed;
            top: 92px;
            left: 766px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
<!-- Start Overlay -->
<div id="overlay" style="display: none"></div>
<!-- End Overlay -->
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<div id="specialBox">
    <button class="x" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">X</button>
</div>
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<!-- Start Normal Page Content -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <button id="qualityButton" class="btn" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">HIGHEST QUALITY</button>
</div>
<!-- End Normal Page Content -->



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the overlay, if open, remains open if I go to another page and come back to the overlay page. I need it to be closed once the page has been left. Thanks Anil!

Comment: Then I think you have to handle it with session variable

Answer (score 1):

In my opionion there are at least two solutions.

- using coockies
- using global function

Second solution:

- create your "popup.js" and call it in html, of course. Your js will be:

  ```
  var Popup = (function () {  
  var isVisible;
   return {
   init: function () {   
    isVisible = false;   
   },    
   show: function() {   
     ....  
   },  
   hide: function() {
     .... 
   },     
   isVisible: function() {  
    return isVisible;  
   }
   };
  }());
  ```

Comment: @T J Hi, with the second option, the overlay, if open, remains open if I go to another page and come back to the overlay page...still going to try the first option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is using Localstorage to do the task. You can read more about localstorage [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

In your case you will have to save timestamp in the variable. And then you can have an if statement on your homepage which checks the time which has elapsed since last time the page was refreshed. Let's say if it is more than 10 minutes or maybe 30 minutes you can show the overlay again. The reason I am saying you will need timestamp is that you will have to unset the variable if the user visits again after some time and is not returning from with-in the website. There is no timeout function in localstorage so you will have to use a tweak like timestamp.

Another way is to save a value in $_SESSION and see if it is set to certain value. If it is then it means it is a returning user else its a new user. But I am not sure if your page is php or not therefore I have mentioned localstorage method first.

If you need any further assistance please do let me know.

Comment: Hi Saad, thanks for your solution. What I need is as following: if the overlay is open, and the page has been left, I want that the overlay is closed when the user comes back to the overlay page. Currently, if the overlay is open, and the user visits another page on my website or even if he visits 10 other websites, when he comes back to that one overlay page, the overlay remains open. I need that to change. I appreciate the time you put in :)

Comment: Yes thats exactly what will happen. You need to store that overlay has been opened once in localstorage. So when the user returns you do an if statement to check if the localstorage variable = alreadyopen. If this condition is true don't show overlay. If this condition is false then show the overlay. Does this help?

Comment: This is just a small example without timestamp to help you understand. localStorage.setItem("overlayopened", "yes"); so on top of your page which has overlay you will use following if condition. if (localStorage.getItem("overlayopened") == "yes") { //dont show over lay } else { //showoverlay }

Comment: Hi Saad, I will first have to figure out how to save a timestamp in the variable, and then how to create an if statement. I'll be trying this as soon as I'm back home. Thanks for your time and help. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: btw, would session storage not be more suited in this case?

Comment: I've just tried the following without any luck: <script>

function toggleOverlay()
{
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("overlayopened")== "yes")
    {
    //dont show overlay
    }
  else
    {
    //showoverlay
    }
  }
}
</script> Is it written correctly?

Comment: Yup the code looks ok. Can you please share a jsfiddle link and let me look at it. I hope you did use .setItem to save the value in the overlayopened